# Is compressive strength closely related to Mohs hardness?

Tags: forces, material-science

Compressive strength is how much inward force a given area of material can withstand before failure. The force tries to compress the atoms closer together.

Mohs hardness is the difficulty of a material to be scratched. Abrasion resistance. However, when an object scratches another, there first is a point of contact where the harder material is forced into the surface of the other, and then lateral forces shear off a grove from the softer material. But at this point of contact, the forces are compressive, trying to force the atoms together, until one of the materials give way.

As such, I would expect materials with a high Mohs hardness to have a high compressive strength and vice versa. This holds for ceramics such as silicon carbide, aluminum oxide, and others which have both a high compressive strength and a high Mohs hardness.

Does this trend hold for most/all materials and to be expected for the above reasons? Are there any counterexamples? If so, what could explain a high Mohs hardness and low compressive strength or vice versa?

Comment: "*The force tries to compress the atoms closer together.*" This is harmless; equitrixial compression can't damage uniform materials. The issue is that a nonequitriaxial stress state causes [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor) that induces failure (by dislocation slip in ductile materials, for example, or crack growth in brittle materials). Many contact mechanics texts (e.g., Fischer-Cripps's *Nanoindentation*) discuss models relating hardness to strength. Yes, these are broadly correlated, with fracture toughness also being a factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a vast topic, with links between hardness (on the Mohs scale and other scales) and strength being investigated in detail for at least a century ([Tabor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Tabor_(physicist)), *The Hardness of Metals*, which references earlier work by [Prandtl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Prandtl) and [Hencky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hencky); Tabor, "Mohs's hardness scale - a physical interpretation," *Proc. Phys. Soc.* B 67 249 (1954); Zhang and Zhang, "General relationship between strength and hardness," *Materials Science and Engineering: A* 529 (2011); Gilman, *Chemistry and Physics of Mechanical Hardness*).

Broadly, geometric models predict that indentation into a surface translates into two-thirds [dilatational stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_stress) and one-third [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor). Dilatational stress simply pushes molecules harmlessly closer together; deviatoric stress—like a 3D version of shear, although it can incorporate non-shear components—tends to tear materials apart. Thus, a good starting estimate, especially for ductile materials, associates the hardness with three times the yield strength. See Ashby and Jones, *Engineering Materials I*, for a very readable derivation:

[image]

Here, the work done by the downward-moving indenter is equated to the shear work done within the indented region and surrounding pile-up.

The factor of three obtained from simple geometry is indeed (approximately) confirmed in a variety of materials, as indicated from a survey by Swab et al. in "Knoop hardness—apparent yield stress relationship in ceramics," *International Journal of Applied Ceramic Technology* 9.3 (2012):

[image]

I'm not convinced that the reported strong aberration for rock salt is real. However, we might expect deviations from the factor-of-three model in brittle materials (such as ceramics), in which indentation could produce crack propagation rather than plastic flow. The existence of long molecular chains and crosslinking in polymers could also have an impact. If you're interested in a particular material class, we could get more specific.

Comment: There are two helpful answers and we can't split bounties so I will award two of them. The Stack Exchange website forces the 2nd bounty to be double the first for some reason, so my standard practice to deal with that (when both answers are roughly comparably useful) is to give the larger one to the author with lower rep.

Comment: Cheers to that!

Answer (score 5):

When compressed, materials primarily deform by shear. An exception is for porous materials, where the pores initially close (the material densifies) and then begins to shear.

The shearing happens in specific directions; typically about 45 degrees to the applied load. In crystalline materials, shear is limited to specific planes and directions. The optimally aligned planes and directions become the first sites of deformation.

In a scratch hardness test, material must flow past an indenter. The indenter often has pyramidal geometry, creating a near-45 degree angle to the material.

The nature of material flow then becomes very similar in compression testing and hardness testing with standard indenters. This is the basis for a lot of good correlations, generally with a linear relation.

However, since your question is specifically about Mohs hardness, which does not involve a standard indenter, there is no fundamental reason to expect a linear relation. On general principle, there will be a positive correlation in most materials.

Some exceptions include surface hardened materials (high scratch hardness but low compressive strength) and materials with a lot of stress raisers/discontinuities such as brittle ceramics (these would break/shatter early under compression, but not visibly so  under scratch deformation). For porous materials, the case could be a little complex as the consolidation is more in compression, and therefore the measured strength could be disproportionate to the hardness.

Comment: There are two helpful answers and we can't split bounties so I will award two of them. The Stack Exchange website forces the 2nd bounty to be double the first for some reason, so my standard practice to deal with that (when both answers are roughly comparably useful) is to give the larger one to the author with lower rep. So I've added the 2nd bounty for this answer and can award in 2 days.

Comment: Thanks, glad the answer was helpful!

Comment: @uhoh I'm glad you found this question helpful enough to put a bounty on. I'm also glad for the answers.